# Text of a dynamically-added Preference is too large

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences, android-styles

I want to add `Preference`s at run-time. The problem is, they look different from statically-defined `Preference`s. I think I may need to pass the `AttributeSet` to the constructor, but I do not know how to get the system's default AttributeSet.

How do I make dynamically-added `Preference`s look like static ones?

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.preference.Preference;
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory;
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceManager;

public static class MyPref extends PreferenceFragmentCompat
{
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s)
    {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.my_preferences);

        final PreferenceCategory category1 = (PreferenceCategory) findPreference("category1");
        Preference p = new Preference(this.getContext());
        p.setTitle("Santos L. Helper");
        p.setSummary("Dynamically added");
        category1.addPreference(p);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
Preference p = new Preference(this.getContext());
```

to

```
Preference p = new Preference(category1.getContext());
```

solved the problem. I guess the lesson here is to always use the context of the closest ancestor.